# I want to maximize returns on a portfolio ensuring risk is below a certain level. Which function can I use for optimization?

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

**Objective function to be maximized** : `pos%*%mu`  where `pos` is the weights row vector and `mu` is the column vector of mean returns of `d` stocks

**Constraints**: 1) `ones%*%pos = 1`  where `ones` is a row vector of 1's of size 1*d (d is the number of stocks)

2) `pos%*%cov%*%t(pos) = rb^2`  # where cov is the covariance matrix of size `d*d` and `rb` is risk budget which is the free parameter whose values will be changed to draw the efficient frontier

**I want to write a code for this optimization problem in R but I can't think of any function or library for help.**

*PS: solve.QP in library quadprog has been used to minimize covariance subject to a target return . Can this function be also used to maximize return subject to a risk budget ?* *How should I specify the Dmat matrix and dvec vector for this problem ?*

**EDIT :**

```
library(quadprog)    

mu <- matrix(c(0.01,0.02,0.03),3,1)

cov # predefined covariance matrix of size 3*3    

pos <- matrix(c(1/3,1/3,1/3),1,3)  # random weights vector 

edr <- pos%*%mu  # expected daily return on portfolio

m1 <- matrix(1,1,3) # constraint no.1 ( sum of weights = 1 )

m2 <- pos%*%cov # constraint no.2

Amat <- rbind(m1,m2)

bvec <- matrix(c(1,0.1),2,1)

solve.QP(Dmat= ,dvec= ,Amat=Amat,bvec=bvec,meq=2)
```

**How should I specify Dmat and dvec ?** I want to optimize over `pos` 
Also, I think I have not specified constraint no.2 correctly. It should make the variance of portfolio equal to the risk budget.

Comment: try adding more useful tags to your question

Comment: A good place to start would be the [CRAN Optimization Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).

Comment: @Gregor I have already seen it but I am a beginner and so I couldn't figure out which function would be suitable. I tried using optimx but no luck

Comment: If you know how to minimize, but you want to maximize, just multiply by -1 and minimize.

Comment: @Gsee Yes, but I don't know how to specify the Dmat matrix and dvec matrix in solve.QP for this problem

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer:  There may be a better way to do this in R.  I am by no means an expert in anything related to R, and I'm making a few assumptions about how R is doing things, notably that you're using an interior-point method.  Also, there is likely an R package for what you're trying to do, but I don't know what it is or how to use it.)

Minimising risk subject to a target return is a linearly-constrained problem with a quadratic objective, looking like this:

```
min        x^T Q x
subject to sum x_i = 1
           sum ret_i x_i >= target
           (and x >= 0 if you want to be long-only).
```

Maximising return subject to a risk budget is quadratically-constrained, however; it looks like this:

```
max        ret^T x
subject to sum x_i = 1
           x^T Q x <= riskbudget
           (and maybe x >= 0).
```

Convex quadratic terms in the objective impose less of a computational cost in an interior-point method compared to introducing a convex quadratic constraint.  With a quadratic objective term, the Q matrix just shows up in the augmented system.   With a convex quadratic constraint, you need to optimise over a more complicated cone containing a second-order cone factor and you need to be careful about how you solve the linear systems that arise.

I would suggest you use the risk-minimisation formulation repeatedly, doing a binary search on the target parameter until you've found a portfolio approximately maximising return subject to your risk budget.  I am suggesting this approach because it is likely sufficient for your needs.

If you really want to solve your problem directly, I would suggest using an interface Todd, Toh, and Tutuncu's [SDPT3](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~mattohkc/sdpt3.html).  This really is overkill; SDPT3 permits you to formulate and solve symmetric cone programs of your choosing.  I would also note that portfolio optimisation problems are particularly special cases of symmetric cone programs; other approaches exist that are reportedly very successful.  Unfortunately, I'm not studied up on them.